# Oracle Using REPLACE with an IN statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string of order types that are separated with dashes like this 00235-3844-42-523-3DF44

I want to take this string in my query and replace the dashes to format it for a WHERE IN clause. Im guessing like this WHERE IN ('00235','3844',
'42','523','3DF44') When I use the REPLACE function after the WHERE IN my query bombs.

Any suggestions.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: What version of oracle?

Comment: Does your current query look like .... WHERE order_types IN ('00235','3844', '42','523','3DF44'); ? Could you please post your current query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this answer is too far away from what you want, but you can accomplish a where clause without tokenizing the string separated with dashes under some assumptions. You could use

```
WHERE INSTR('00235-3844-42-523-3DF44',str_to_find)!=0
```

Reason I am suggesting INSTR is that tokenization can be more costly and be more complicated.

Comment: In my example the strings I would be looking for in the field order_types would be 00235 or 3844 or 42 or 523 or 3DF44. Would INSTR still work?

Comment: This works and I learned something from you today. Give me a year or two and I will be good at this.

Comment: To make it more robust (i.e. so that `24` doesn't match `1245`) I'd put terminators around it all, e.g. `INSTR('-00235-3844-42-523-3DF44-','-'||str_to_find||'-')`